# How can I use system icons

Tags: android, resources

Im totally new to Android development.

I would like to use buttons/images like these:

[image]

in my application. I don't want to reproduce them (create new png files etc.).
I guess resources like these are somewhere in Android.

1. How I can use them?
2. Is this common in Android Development to rely on system built-in images?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean where you can find iconography for your Android Development, you can find the Android Icons [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html).

You'll find useful information and a link to a zip file with iconograpy ready for different device screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can write smth like this in your xml layout-file:

```
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_login"
            android:id="@+id/my_button"/>
```

Or you can download icons from here: 
https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Comment: So, `ic_menu_login` is built-in icon? Where I can find list of these?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to developer site, it may help you https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

For image generating visit http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html
and press **SELECT IMAGE** after generating you can download.

Answer (score 0):

In the android resource folder used for putting the images. And we will get that images through code.

Try to take transprent images. So that will not have background.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/odesk_logo" />
```